# Reading an UTF-8 encoded file into std::u32string without intermediate buffering

Tags: c++11

Having worked quite long time with Unicode and C++ I thought this would be a simple thing to accomplish, especially with the new C++11 `std::codecvt_utf8` facet. Though it turned out to be a diffcult task. What I want is to read a file encoded in UTF-8 into a u32string (converting it from UTF-8 to UTF-32 implicitly). Sure, I could load the entire content into a buffer and convert that using `std::wstring_convert`. But that doubles the memory footprint when loading a file. So I tried to use a std::wifstream and imbue a locale with a utf-8 facet like this:

```
std::wifstream stream(fileName, std::ios::binary);
stream.imbue(std::locale(stream.getloc(), new std::codecvt_utf8<char32_t, 0x10ffff, std::consume_header>));

std::u32string data;
for (char32_t c; stream >> c; )
  data += c;
```

which looks like a straight forward implementation. It only doesn't compile. wifstream's element type is `wchar_t`, so you can only use `wchar_t` in the loop, like this:

```
std::u32string data;
for (wchar_t c; stream >> c; )
  data += c;
```

(at least with clang, VC++ also accepts char32_t there, but that doesn't change anything). After fixing this several other problems remain, though:

- In Visual C++ wchar_t is only 16bit (no UTF-32 then, we don't consider surrogate pairs here).
- Using `char32_t` for the facet essentially disables conversion. The iteration over the stream returns the original UTF-8 content, both in clang and VC++.
- Using `wchar_t` also for the facet makes it work in clang, but not in VC++, because in clang `wchar_t` is 32bit wide, while (as mentioned already) it is only 16bit in VC++.

So, what is the correct approach here? With the lock into wchar_t for the facet I cannot even use a different data type. I also tried defining a `basic_ifstream<char32_t>` but that requires additional typedefs, hence I didn't follow that path further.

Comment: `wifstream` is `basic_ifstream<wchar_t>`. Try with `basic_ifstream<char32_t>`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, as I wrote in the question, I tried that already, but that alone doesn't cut it. It requires more typedefs for types used by basic_ifstream.

Comment: I honestly do not understand what your question is. Are you asking how to work around the problem that the `wchar_t` type has different sizes on Clang and MSVC? There is no magic. You just have to use a typedef for an appropriately-sized type depending on the environment. Can you explain why "that requires additional typedefs" is a show-stopping problem?

Comment: Well, it's simple to read UTF-8 data, it's simple to read UTF-16 data, so I believe it should be equally simple to do that for UTF-32. I just haven't found the right approach. Defining a custom stream type is an option, but looks as if that requires significant work. It's not done by just defining the stream typedef.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems there is no way using a facet and imbue that in a stream, so I went with an intermediate buffer, which is a very elegant solution too, only that it doubles (more or less) the memory needed to load the content. Use a byte (file) stream in binary mode to call this:

```
void load(std::istream &stream)
{
  static std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<char32_t>, char32_t> utfConverter;

  std::string s((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(stream)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
  _data = utfConverter.from_bytes(s);
}
```